# Dataframe loc with multiple string value conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image: Example]

Hi, given this dataframe is it possible to fetch the Number value associated with certain conditions using df.loc? This is what i came up with so far.

```
if df.loc[(df["Tags"]=="Brunei") & (df["Type"]=="Host"),"Number"]:
```

I want the output to be 1. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: Well what does your output look like? Please do not upload data as screenshot. Instead an copyable snippet would be nice.

Comment: df.loc[(df["Tags"]=="Brunei") & (df["Type"]=="Host"), "Number"] will give the result you want. Note that the output is a pandas Series, so you shouldn't consider it as conditional (shouldn't put "if" behind it).

Comment: I think, this will do the work: `df["Number"].loc[(df["Tags"]=="Brunei") & (df["Type"]=="Host")]`

Comment: Add `.iloc[0]` and a validation check to make sure that the returned series only has one element.

Comment: Thanks Morteza, coco18 and ifly6. Those managed to get me my answers

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right way, but you have to pass **".values[0]"** in the end of the .loc statement to extract the only value that you got in the pandas Series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Tags': ['Brunei', 'China'],
'Type': ['Host', 'Address'],
'Number': [1, 1192]
}
)

display(df)

series = df.loc[(df["Tags"]=="Brunei") & (df["Type"]=="Host"),"Number"]
print(type(series))
value = df.loc[(df["Tags"]=="Brunei") & (df["Type"]=="Host"),"Number"].values[0]
print(type(value))
```